# Find HTML table row which has special text

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find HTML table row which has special text using regular expression.

In above table first cell text 'Total',I want to replace first row.

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Total</td><td>255</td></tr>
    <tr><td>XYz</td><td>441</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Regular expressions are almost never a good choice for parsing HTML. Any reason you want to use regular expressions?

Comment: You should use a DOM parser, such as the HTMLAgilityPack, rather than regular expressions for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, this will match and allow you to replace that line.

```
(<tr><td>Total.*?</tr>)
```

However, if possible I also encourage you to use something else like [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (will gracefully handle malformed HTML) or a plain XML parser if you are lucky enough to have strict XHTML markup (rare).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't reliably match HTML with just regular expressions.  This is because HTML is a [context-free language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) rather than a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) parseable using regular expressions.

Consider using an HTML parser instead.  For C#, the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is a good choice, as mgnoonan mentioned in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

few assumptions has to be made, Your HTML input string is valid HTML (well-formed) or else the function will ***fail*** :P

try this

```
    private static MatchCollection GetSpecialTables(string inputStr, string ftrName)
    {
        try
        {
            return Regex.Matches(inputStr, string.Format(@"<table>\s+<tr><td>{0}</td>.+?</table>", Regex.Escape(ftrName)), RegexOptions.Singleline);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            // Syntax error in the regular expression, handle it
            return null;
        }
    }
    // use it this way!
    static void Main()
    {

        var matches = GetSpecialTables(myHtml, "Total");
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            // match.Value;
        }

    }
```